# docker ubuntu sourceing after starting image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I built myself an image for ROS. I run it while mounting my original home on the host and some tricks to get graphics as well. After starting the shell inside docker I always need to execute two source commands. One of the files to be sourced are actually inside the container, but the other resides in my home, which only gets mounted on starting the container. I would have these two files sourced automatically.

I tried adding

```
RUN bash -c "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash"
```

to the image file, but this did not actually source it. Using `CMD` instead of run didn't drop me into the container's shell (I assume it finished executing source and then exited?). I don't even have an idea how to source the file that is only available after startup. What would I need to do?

Comment: your RUN command is valid only in the context of this RUN, and is "forgotten" when the next command of your Dockerfile executes. It is like if you do this source in a terminal, and then open another terminal. What is ROS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: you need to perform this step as part of your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`, and for something like a source command, you need a step after that in the shell to run your app, or whatever shell you'd like. If you just want a bash shell as your command, then put your `source` command inside something like your `.bashrc` file. Or you can run something like:

```
bash -c "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash && bash"
```

as your command.

---

> One of the files to be sourced are actually inside the container, but the other resides in my home, which only gets mounted on starting the container.
>
> ...
>
> I tried adding ... to the image file

Images are built using temporary containers that only see your Dockerfile instructions and the context sent with that to run the build. Containers use that built image and all of your configuration, like volumes, to run your application. There's a hard divider between those two steps, image build and container run, and your volumes are not available during that image build step.

Each of those `RUN` steps being performed for the image build are done in a temporary container that only stores the output of the filesystem when it's finished. Changes to your environment, a cd into another directory, spawned processes or services in the background, or anything else not written to the filesystem when the command spawned by `RUN` exits, will be lost. This is one reason you will see commands chained together in a single long `RUN` command, and it's why you have `ENV` and `WORKDIR` commands in the Dockerfile.

Comment: With your proposed line things ALMOST work out, but it seems that starting a new bash process after sourcing will e.g. somehow reset the $PATH (but not new environment variables created by source). The normal solution would be to use the .bashrc, but since I'm mounting my own home, that would mean having to edit the bashrc of the host machine, but that would not be a good idea, since the host machine does not have the file to be sourced. I found a workaround, I created an alternative bashrc (bashrc_ros) and set `ENTRYPOINT bash --rcfile .bashr_roc` but I still get the overwritten $PATH thing.

Comment: I tinkered with the alternative .bashrc and it worked out after a while, I was probably missing something, but it's all good now :)